# Missing libpq header files on CentOS when attempting to install psycopg2 module

Tags: python-2.7, centos, psycopg2, postgresql-9.3, libpq

I have been searching the web hours on end for several days and I am unable to install psycopg2 library on my Linux machine (CentOS - 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 GNU/Linux).

I know that the problem is that I am missing the libpq header files since I am getting this message after attempting pip install psycopg2: `libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory`

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#install-from-source

Almost all the articles I found pointed me to use apt-get on CentOS but apt-get is not a standard tool on CentOS 6.3 so I've been trying `yum install` instead.

However, every time I try to use `sudo yum install` to download something the package is not available. For example:

`yum install postgresql-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
drivesrvr                                                         | 2.2 kB     00:00
No package postgresql-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do`

I've tried this for:

1. yum install postgresql-server
2. yum install python-devel
3. service postgresql initdb
4. service postgresql start
5. yum install python-psycopg2

Any ideas? Without the the libpq header files I can't install the psycopg2 module that is necessary for my Python program. This is for Python 2.7.12. And PostgreSQL 9.3.13.

Answer (score 9):

I had this exact issue on Fedora 2016.09 box on Amazon. I was able to install postgresql-devel via yum, but that didn't do the trick; the version seemed to be out of date.

I solved it using:

```
sudo yum install /usr/include/libpq-fe.h
```

This installs an updated version of postgresql-devel which allows psycopg2 to compile correctly when installing through pip.

Comment: This is only solution which works for me. Thanks @ataki.